# Postulates of Newtonian mechanics vs Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

We know that Newtonian mechanics have postulates related to space, time and inertial frames. What about the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms? Are they same or different? How they differ from Newtonian postulates?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614099/2451

Comment: Hi talari suresh. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Ok qmechanic, but i deleted one of them